# How to assign dynamic id into on id of div

Tags: jquery

Here is the function in which I want to add the value of id

```
function changeStatus(id,status){
    var url = 'load_status.php?id='+id+'&status='+status;
    alert(url);
    $('#hideStatus_'+id).hide();
    $('#status_' + id).load(url)
}
```

id is come by the calling of function.
My problem is this $('#status'+id) is not taking the numerical value of id.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide context (html and the rest of js), this should work.

Comment: You need to create a jsfiddle, so we can see why your id is not the numerical value of id